# How to make projector only affect some specific part of object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, effects, projector

I'm working on Unity3D for a fish shooting game. I'm implementing the underwater caustic effect for fishs. I'm using "BlobLightProjector" in StandardAsset of Unity with an attached script to change the texture every frame by :

```
public Texture2D[] frames;
private int frameIndex;
private Projector projector;
...
// repeat every frame
projector.material.SetTexture("_ShadowTex", frames[frameIndex]);
frameIndex = (frameIndex + 1) % frames.Length;
```

My list caustic textures look like this :

[image: List caustic texture]

Here is what I achieved :
[image: My achieve]

Now the problem is I want the projector only affect the upper parts of the fish (even though I rotate my fish to any direction), that is something look like this :
[image: My wish]

Could you give me some advices how to do it, or other solution don't use projector is good so.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you're going to need to use a custom Shader. I'll be honest I'm no expert on them but there was a Unite 2016 on shaders which had an example very similar to this.

I'm sorry I don't have any code for you but I hope this will be at least a small step in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify **Assets\Standard Assets\Effects\Projectors\Shaders\ProjectorLight.shader** the following way:

1. you need to create a new variable that is going to be passed from the vertex shader to the pixel shader in the `v2f` struct: `half fade : TEXCOORD3;`
2. then you need to be able to use the normal in the vertex shader. An easy choice is to use `appdata_base` instead of only passing the vertex position: `v2f vert (appdata_base v)` and modify the call to the position by appending `v.` to `vertex` everywhere.
3. you then compute the fade factor based on the normal: I chose to just clamp the world normal's vertical axis (since it ranges from -1 to 1) `o.fade = saturate(mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.normal).y);`. `saturate()` clamps to 0-1, the matrix `mul()` converts to world space.
4. finally apply the fade to the result in the pixel shader `texS.rgb *= _Color.rgb * 8.0 * i.fade;` (I increase the range by 8 because otherwise values can never be brighter than 1, but that's up to your liking)

   ```
           CGPROGRAM
       #pragma vertex vert
       #pragma fragment frag
       #pragma multi_compile_fog
       #include "UnityCG.cginc"

       struct v2f {
           float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
           float4 uvShadow : TEXCOORD0;
           float4 uvFalloff : TEXCOORD1;
           UNITY_FOG_COORDS(2)
           half fade : TEXCOORD3;
       };

       float4x4 unity_Projector;
       float4x4 unity_ProjectorClip;

       v2f vert (appdata_base v)
       {
           v2f o;
           o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
           o.uvShadow = mul (unity_Projector, v.vertex);
           o.uvFalloff = mul (unity_ProjectorClip, v.vertex);
           o.fade = saturate(mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.normal).y);
           UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o, o.pos);
           return o;
       }

       fixed4 _Color;
       sampler2D _ShadowTex;
       sampler2D _FalloffTex;

       fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
       {
           fixed4 texS = tex2Dproj (_ShadowTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvShadow));
           texS.rgb *= _Color.rgb * 8.0 * i.fade;
           texS.a = 1.0-texS.a;

           fixed4 texF = tex2Dproj (_FalloffTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvFalloff));
           fixed4 res = texS * texF.a;

           UNITY_APPLY_FOG_COLOR(i.fogCoord, res, fixed4(0,0,0,0));
           return res;
       }
       ENDCG
   ```